# How to click on a href link by using python scripts and selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, href

I am trying to get Selenium to click on a specific href such as

```
<a href="publications.html">Publications</a>
```

I tried doing

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Publications.html').click()
```

but it gives me the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should read the docs and some tutorials on how to use `find_element_by_link_text()`.

Answer (score 3):

`.find_element_by_link_text()` finds an `A` tag by the text inside the `A` tag, e.g.

```
<a href="publications.html">Publications</a>
```

You can find this tag using

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Publications")
```

BUT... if you want to find an `A` tag by the href, you need a different approach.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='publications.html']")
```

This is a CSS selector. You can find more info on them in the links below.

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[CSS Selector Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
find_element_by_link_text('Publications.html')
```

to

```
find_element_by_link_text('Publications')
```

Comment: OP is asking how to find it by the href, not link text.

Comment: @JeffC No, OP is asking How to click on a href link and already using `find_element_by_link_text`...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Clearly OP is new to Selenium and is confusing things. OP was using `.find_element_by_link_text()` but using the href, which OP said they wanted to use, instead of the actual link text. Only OP knows exactly what they want but all indications look to me like they are trying to actually get the element by href.

Comment: @JeffC Basically OP wants to click on link but he mentioned click on a specific href.. this is confusing things.. Anyway OP got both solution...with link text and with href also...thanks..:)